# Andengine settext not works after Resume

Tags: android, text, andengine, resume

I have a main activity A which calls an Intent B. Things work fine EXCEPT for: if I press back button to switch back to A, and then press a button to call B (onResume): The settext method does not work, i.e. the text displays only its initial value (in constructor). Here is the case:

```
txtResult = new Text(60f, 20f, this.mFont, "Instructions",textLength,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

Then somewhere in the activity, I use settext to "Updated", the txtResult displays it correctly ("Updated").
After that, I switch back to main activity (A), then back to B, the txtResult is still "Instructions", not "Updated".
If I try to settext, it does not work either.

Comment: Please show your `onResume` method code.

Comment: I did not implement the `onResume` method. My temporary solution is `mscene.detachChild(txtResult)` on `onBackPressed()`. What should I do in the `onResume`?